# Get the Product tags for the current product only in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, custom-taxonomy

How can I display only the product tags for the current single product page and not all the products tags?

I've found questions about most popular tags but not for that.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use the function [wp_get_post_terms()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_terms) function for WooCommerce 'product_tag' custom taxonomy and a defined **product id** this way:

```
$output = array();

// get an array of the WP_Term objects for a defined product ID
$terms = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_id(), 'product_tag' );

// Loop through each product tag for the current product
if( count($terms) > 0 ){
    foreach($terms as $term){
        $term_id = $term->term_id; // Product tag Id
        $term_name = $term->name; // Product tag Name
        $term_slug = $term->slug; // Product tag slug
        $term_link = get_term_link( $term, 'product_tag' ); // Product tag link

        // Set the product tag names in an array
        $output[] = '<a href="'.$term_link.'">'.$term_name.'</a>';
    }
    // Set the array in a coma separated string of product tags for example
    $output = implode( ', ', $output );

    // Display the coma separated string of the product tags
    echo $output;
}
```

Tested and works.

You can replace `get_the_id()` by a dynamic product Id variable too.

Comment: Thank you very much, that worked! But how could i display the tags with their links too? Right now i display only the title of the tag.

Comment: sorry for that and thanks for reminding me. Thanks for the code, it's exactly what i was looking for for many days.

Answer (score 4):

You can now use the [`wc_get_product_tag_list()`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/wc-product-functions.php#L1129) function to get a list of the product's tags. It supports providing a separator along with before and after elements.

**Example**

```
<?php
    global $product;
?>
    <div class="product-tags">
        <?php echo wc_get_product_tag_list( $product->get_id(), ', ' ); ?>
    </div>
```